# Request Headers information for any url

Tags: php

This code `print_r($_SERVER)` give the current URL information but I want to be able to pass any URL in `curl` take the request header information, eg:

- Pragma,
- keep-alive,
- Accept-Charset,
- Host,
- Connection,
- Cache-Control,
- Accept-Encoding,etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print all information from an HTTP request to the screen, in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136253/how-to-print-all-information-from-an-http-request-to-the-screen-in-php)

Comment: This [has](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751148/how-to-capture-full-http-request-data-headers-and-body-with-php) [been](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136253/how-to-print-all-information-from-an-http-request-to-the-screen-in-php) answered a few times already, please make a simple search before posting new questions!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get request headers in php using any url like(www.w3schools.com)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334075/how-to-get-request-headers-in-php-using-any-url-likewww-w3schools-com)

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com';

print_r(get_headers($url));
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: but this code for responce header we are not get host name